# IValidatableObject is not called

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I have a problem that IValidatableObject  is not called... I tried debugging whatsoever. And yes model validation passes, so in my opinion it should be called.
Here is my task:
I have 2 dates and want to compare them. If start date is later than end date pop up me an error.
Here is the code:

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if(endDate < startDate)
            yield return new ValidationResult("End date cannot be earlier than start date.", new[] { "startDate" });
    }
```

here is my controller that I inherit IValidatableObject interface:

```
 public class MyVacationModel : GeneralEditModel<Vacation>, IValidatableObject
```

Maybe You have any better solution for this validation?

Comment: Do you call ModelState.IsValid in the controllerAction?

Comment: Yes, got ModelState.IsValid in my controller. I can only call this method by writing base.Validate, is there any other way to invoke ti automatically?

Comment: Well the issue was that there was ignoring all the validation from mvc side, just a custom one, so that is why the method was not invoked.